# Pop translations used during CGContext

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, pdf, cgcontext

As you can see in the code below I do some transformations on my UIView before writing some text. It seems though that the position of the text is affected by the aforementioned transformations.

Is there any way to 'pop' these displacements so I can then write my text in relation to the original 0,0 coordinate?

```
//turn PDF upsidedown
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(100, aUIView.bounds.size.height+300);
transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 0.5, -0.5);
CGContextConcatCTM(pdfContext, transform);


// Draw view into PDF
// Is renderInContext deprecated? Something to look into. 
[aUIView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];


CGContextSelectFont (pdfContext, "Helvetica", 14, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (pdfContext, kCGTextFill);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (pdfContext, 0, 0, 0, 1);
CGContextSetTextMatrix(pdfContext, CGAffineTransformMake(1.0,0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
const char *text = "THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPED OVER THE LAZY DOG TEST 1";
CGContextShowTextAtPoint (pdfContext, 10.0, 10.0, text, strlen(text));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think CGContextSaveGState(cntx) and CGContextRestoreGState(cntx) are what you are looking for.